# Azure ASG internal connectivity

Tags: azure, networking, azure-nsg

I created an application security group, assigned it to two VMs and there is a lot more in that resource group but my question is when I RDP into one of the VMs, I cannot ping the other VM and or reach a website hosted on the other VM. Plus because of an NSG, I am able to reach that website from my local machine.

I thought using ASGs mean, I don't have to do anything else for connected VMs to talk to each other? Also of note, if I open up the ASG to everything in the NSG, I am able to ping and reach the site from the other VM. What am I missing?

Both VMs are in the same vnet and subnet. Screenshot of NIC of one of the VMs below:

[image: NIC Showing ASG and NSG rules]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> when I RDP into one of the VMs, I cannot ping the other VM and or
>   reach a website hosted on the other VM. Plus because of an NSG, I am
>   able to reach that website from my local machine.

You're able to connect to the other VM from the VM because VMs in the same virtual network can communicate with each other over any port, by default. This means you can access the other VM using its **private IP address** from one VM. Note, by default, Firewall inside the VM may disable the ICMP packages, you may use `netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="ICMP Allow incoming V4 echo request" protocol=icmpv4:8,any dir=in action=allow` to enable the ICMP inbound traffic if you work on Windows Azure VM or temporarily turn windows firewall off to test this when you ping each other.

In this case, you may check the above first. If you still do not ping VMs or reach a website hosted on the other VM2 from the VM1 inside the private network. I may think that something is blocking on the NSG side. It is not a good way to use PING test the VMs connectivity. You could use telnet to verify if the specific port is blocking.

> I thought using ASGs mean, I don't have to do anything else for
>   connected VMs to talk to each other?

Yes, you don't have to do anything else for connected VMs to talk to each other as they already in the same subnet where they can communicate with each other.

You may refer to more details about [Application security groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/security-overview#application-security-groups).

Comment: Hi Nancy, thank you for your reply! The VM1 and VM2 nics don't have any rules that block each other. In fact I even tried adding a rule to allow ASG-to-ASG specifically. But still, VM1 cannot reach VM2. I've updated my question with a screenshot of the ASG that both VM nics are attached to. Please take a look and let me know what I need to do. Thanks again!

Comment: @Anand, I re-edit my reply to make it clearer. Could you use its private IP address when you let VM1 communicate with VM2? Also, you do not need to add a rule to allow ASG-to-ASG specifically as there is a rule to allow vnet to vnet.

Comment: Thanks again Nancy, I did try IP flow verify on these VMs, here is the interesting thing - Azure denies my connection from VM1 to VM2 when I use public IP of VM1 based on the DenyAllInbound rule BUT it allows me to connect if I use private IP of VM1. However, this doesn't help me when I'm trying to use a browser in VM1 to reach a website hosted on VM2.

Comment: @Anand, It's normal if you use private IP since both VMs are in a subnet, they can reach without going to the Internet. If you want to access the VM using public IP. You could bind a static public IP to each NIC of VMs, then add these public IPs as the source in the inbound rule of allowing traffic to ASG. This is the same as your other machines to access the website hosted on Azure VM.